# Key on Norwegian keyboard not mapped correctly

Tags: keyboard, pop-os

I recently installed Pop OS Linux distro. Works great! Except an interesting problem. I use Norwegian keyboard. It mostly works as expected. However, the dash/underscore key doesn't work properly. Nothing happens when I click it. However, if I switch to Swedish keyboard layout (pretty similar, some difference in letters), the key works fine and as intended (dash when pressed, underscore when shift+key is pressed). Any way for me to map the key properly, or do a reinstall to fix this?[image]

Comment: Run `xev | grep key`, focus the `xev` window, and type the key with underscore. What output do you get?